# How does one create system files with file names with UTF-8 characters from a Tomcat/Java app?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, filesystems

I have a java server app that creates UTF-8 file system names.

Unfortunately, when I look at the file names the non-ascii characters of the file names are displayed with ‘?’. How do I get the system to display the appropriate UTF-8 characters?

For example, I can create files with Greek characters from a terminal via touch and all the UTF-8 characters are displayed correctly.

**System specs**

- Linux CentOS 6.0 2.6.18.8-xenU #1 SMP Thu May 13 11:11:51 PDT 2010
  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Tomcat 6
- Java 1.6

**Configurations**

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I even execute the following at startup:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
System.setProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
System.setProperty("user.language", "en_US.UTF-8");
System.setProperty("user.country", "en_US.UTF-8");
System.setProperty("sun.jnu.encoding", "UTF8");
```

And where I create the file:

```
fullPathName = new String(fullPathName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
input = new BufferedInputStream(is, STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);
output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fullPathName),
STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE);

// Read file from memory and write it to disk.
int r;
byte[] buf = new byte[STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((r = input.read(buf)) != -1) {
        output.write(buf, 0, r);
}

output.close();
output = null;
input.close();
input = null;
```

Comment: What's with all those horrible "smart quotes"?

Comment: The line `fullPathName = new String(fullPathName.getBytes("UTF-8"));` makes no sense. You're converting chars to bytes using UTF-8 and then again converting those bytes to chars, but then using platform default encoding (which seems in your case to be UTF-8 already). To do it "right", you should be supplying `"UTF-8"` as 2nd argument of `new String(bytes, charset)` constructor. But again, this is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of String in Java is that it contains a string of Unicode code points, internally stored as UTF-16. However this should be an implementation detail for many of the String methods. So getBytes is going to return a byte array containing the UTF-8 encoding of whatever codepoints are in fullPathName, and then the String constructor you pass those bytes to will convert it to the internal encoding of the String assuming that the bytes have the platform's encoding. If we assume that you've set things up so that Java thinks UTF-8 is the platform encoding, then you'll end up with a String that has the exact same contents as the original String.

So the question is, why are you doing that? Did you do something like put UTF-8 code units into the string and then expect getBytes("UTF-8") to return a byte array containing exactly those code units?

You should check on what the String fullPathName contains when you pass it to FileOutputStream, because the most likely thing is that you're doing something that's causing the wrong thing to be passed in.

Another possibility is that your shell isn't actually using UTF-8, so when you create a file via touch using greek characters you're actually just using whatever is correct for how your shell is set up. So when Java creates a file with a name using the UTF-8 encoding, your shell is correctly showing that the UTF-8 filename isn't whatever encoding the shell is configured for.

You can show the actual bytes used in the file name by piping it through hexdump, and then figure out manually if the filenames are UTF-8 or whatever.

Oh, and one more thing. The file system format does have an effect, so you might want to list that. Although I assume you're using some typical linux file system format which doesn't enforce any filename encoding, some file system formats like NTFS or HFS+ store filenames in a known encoding, and the APIs have to handle that. For example (the C function) fopen on might transcode from the byte array given to it to UTF-16 using the current system encoding in order to figure out the UTF-16 code units to store the file under NTFS. But other file systems don't enforce any encoding, so fopen would just take the byte array you give it and store that as the file name. This is going to lead to differences in behavior can actually cause problems for file access APIs in environments that use Strings of known encodings. For example, if you have a function that takes a UTF-16 String as a filename and the file you want to open was named using an ISO-8859-1 string of bytes, but the system's encoding is UTF-8, then that file access API probably just can't open that file.

This whole thing is just really screwed up.

I'm adding an example. The following file is saved as UTF-8 and named 'HelloWorld.java'

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fullPathName = "ΘΙϗϕξ.tmp";
        for(int i=0;i<fullPathName.length();++i) {
            System.out.format("char: %x\n",
                              (int)fullPathName.charAt(i));
        }

        try {
            BufferedOutputStream output =
              new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(fullPathName));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("caught exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Built and run using `javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld` the output is:

```
char: 152
char: f2
char: 152
char: f4
char: 153
char: f3
char: 153
char: ef
char: 152
char: e6
char: 2e
char: 74
char: 6d
char: 70
```

This output indicates that the wrong characters are in the string. Apparently, even though my system is set up with the en_US.UTF-8 locale java doesn't assume UTF-8 source code. Built and run using `javac -encoding UTF-8 && java HelloWorld` I get the following correct output:

```
char: 398
char: 399
char: 3d7
char: 3d5
char: 3be
char: 2e
char: 74
char: 6d
char: 70
```

Now the string contains the correct UTF-16 code units and creates the file "ΘΙϗϕξ.tmp" which shows up in the directory:

```
0 [Hydrogen·bames·~/tmp]
⑆ ls
HelloWorld.class
HelloWorld.java
ΘΙϗϕξ.tmp
0 [Hydrogen·bames·~/tmp]
⑆ ls *.tmp | hexdump -C
00000000  ce 98 ce 99 cf 97 cf 95  ce be 2e 74 6d 70 0a     |...........tmp.|
0000000f
```

As you can see, FileOutputStream correctly translated to the locale encoding to create the file because `ce 98` is the correct UTF-8 encoding of `U+0398` or 'Θ'.

It's not clear if the filename showing up correctly in your log files is enough to say that the string's content is really okay. Also it would be helpful to know the filename you're getting more than just that some of the characters look like '?'. What are the actual values stored? You can use hexdump to find out.

Comment: I agree that I do not need to recreate the file name: fullPathName = new String(fullPathName.getBytes("UTF-8")); I removed that line of code and when I read fullPathName in the logs the string is still displayed using the correct character encoding. However when I list the file in a terminal these files have  '?' characters.

Comment: There are files in the same directory that have and display greek characters in the terminal.

Comment: How are you checking the encoding of the filenames from the terminal? What encoding is the shell using? What encoding is the terminal using?

Comment: @JohnDell'Aera "What is screwed up?" File access and how it interacts with encodings across different platforms, file system drivers, and other variables.

Comment: A terminal locale dump is posted above.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem.

cd /dev/ chmod 666 urand null random zero

vi /usr/sbin/tomcat6 CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dencoding=UTF-8"

I did not test to check if -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 is sufficient, but I think sun.jnu.encoding is for encoding the file names, file.encoding for encoding the contents of the file and encoding for encoding java strings.

I found the solution to my problem. 

1. cd /dev/
   chmod 666 urand null random zero

2. vi /usr/sbin/tomcat6
   CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dencoding=UTF-8"

Comment: Actually, I backed out the CATALINA_OPTS changes. Changing the permissions on said /dev locations was sufficient. Furthermore, I  should not have set CATALINA_OPTS without appending the existing options.